# How can pydantic validator access 2nd attribute?

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

How can I make a pydantic validator validate input against another **class object** (not another input arg, but really another object sitting in the class definition, such as a property, or function). --> I would love to call `self.xx`.

So, I know how to validate one input arg against another input arg (e.g., validating that the `color` is green if `plant` is a tree):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class MyClass(BaseModel):

    plant: str
    color: str
   
    @validator('color')
    def tree_is_green(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        if values['plant'] == 'tree':
            if v != 'green':
                raise ValueError('tree must be green')
        return v
```

It will bark at blue trees, etc., while roses can be of any color:

```
my_plant = MyClass(color='blue', plant='rose')      # works
my_plant = MyClass(color='blue', plant='tree')      # fails
my_plant = MyClass(color='green', plant='tree')      # works
```

So far, so good.

Now, how can I generalize this, and use a `property`? Say the validator becomes a bit more complicated than just a `==`, and I don't want to copy/paste all the functionality of my functions and properties into the validator.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class MyClass(BaseModel):

    plant: str
    color: str

    @property
    def is_tree(self) -> bool:
        return self.plant == 'tree'

    @validator('color')
    def tree_is_green(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        if values['is_tree'] is True:
            if v != 'green':
                raise ValueError('tree must be green')
        return v
```

The above code fails always, no matter what instance I try to create:

```
my_plant = MyClass(color='green', plant='tree')
>>> KeyError: 'is_tree'
```

I tried to replace the `values[]` by a desperate attempt to `cls`, but to no avail. Using the below will never return an error - and it's simply not validating anything:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class MyClass(BaseModel):

    plant: str
    color: str

    @property
    def is_tree(self) -> bool:
        return self.plant == 'tree'

    @validator('color')
    def tree_is_green(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        if cls.is_tree is True:
            if v != 'green':
                raise ValueError('tree must be green')
        return v
```

leads to unwanted output:

```
my_plant = MyClass(color='blue', plant='tree')
print(my_plant)
plant='tree' color='blue'
```

Is there any way to construct a validator that is based on functionality/objects of the class, rather than only the input args, or static variables? Conceptually, it should work, as the property `is_tree` does not depend on `color`, so any form of circular reference is excluded.. and if that blew up, I would humbly accept it and think of a better validator..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a pydantic `validator` is a `classmethod`, it unfortunately won't be able to use the `@property` as you're expecting. The `@property` is designed to work on an instance of `MyClass`, similar to any other instance method; however, during the "validation" stage of pydantic, the instance isn't yet created, and it's calling `validator`s as class methods, so it only has access to other `classmethod`s and class attributes.

You could switch `is_tree` to a `classmethod` and pass it the plant value:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class MyClass(BaseModel):

    plant: str
    color: str

    @classmethod
    def is_tree(cls, plant_val) -> bool:
        return plant_val == 'tree'

    @validator('color')
    def tree_is_green(cls, v, values):
        if cls.is_tree(values['plant']) and v != 'green':
                raise ValueError('tree must be green')
        return v

MyClass(color='blue', plant='rose') # no problems
MyClass(color='green', plant='tree') # no problems
MyClass(color='blue', plant='tree') # ValidationError: color -> tree must be green
```

Comment: Unbelievable - after almost 2 years :D -- Thank you so much. I had indeed "ignored" this until today, usually doing copy/paste for more elaborate validators (e.g., validating a dataframe schema against a dictionary), holding a copy of the class attr in the validator. Thank you! :)

Comment: No problem! Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 4):

You can get access to other values by paying another argument `values` to the validator, see the `passwords_match` validator [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/).

Comment: Thanks, that's a great input. I have since edited the question above, to make it clearer what I want: The question really is about accessing a class attribute, not a 2nd input arg